# Obter uma lista com valores de um mesmo tipo

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

**Gostaria de obter uma lista, somente, com os nomes das variáveis (keys) que são do tipo "object"**

Porém, não estou conseguindo obter resultado desejado. Alguém poderia me dar um help?

[image: Situação do meu código]

Comment: João, precisamos entender melhor o seu problema. O contexto está muito fechado. Por favor, detalhe o que você pretende fazer, como está fazendo e aí sim, a dificuldade que está encontrando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc pode usar um método próprio do draframe para isso: `select_dtypes()`. Como no final vc quer o nome das colunas (variáveis) do tipo `object`, basta vc fazer o seguinte:

```
list(x.select_dtypes(include='object').columns)
```

O `select_dtypes()` retorna todo o dataframe com as colunas do tipo especificado. Vc pode conferir melhor sobre esse método [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html). O `.columns` é apenas para pegar o nome das colunas.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Valeu amigo, funcionou do jeitinho. thks!